# ActivityNotFoundException while integrating AdMob

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, admob

I've seen similar question like this but non of the solutions have helped me. I followed the guide lines provided in this link https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start to integrate AdMob into my app.

My xml files and java classes are as follows:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SpoilerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


</application>
```

I've added `<string name="banner_ad_unit_id"></string>` into my **strings.xml**

And `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>` into my **activity_main.xml**

It's integrated into the **Activity.java class** like this:

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2. and my minSdkVersion is 14 and targetSdk is 22.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: I somehow managed to resolve my first issue. Now it's just the fact that the test ad never shows up. Ill look through logcat to see if I find anything interesting

Comment: To receive Test Ads you need to add Test Devices, [Check out](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder#addTestDevice%28java.lang.String%29)